# Python: use the same class instance in multiple modules

Tags: python, class, oop, instance

I have a class called EventManager, and am calling this class in each module I have. I thought  of creating a single instance of the EventManager in the main file, and use that instance in each module. My questions are:

- Is this the right way in my case? Note that I don't want to create multiple instances of the EventManager as it parses a file each time it is called, and that file can contain large amount of data.
- what is the best way to do it, given that I want less memory usage?

Comment: I would like to know how to implement singleton pattern in Python

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use a singleton. Here is a simple example:

```
def singleton(cls):
    return cls()

@singleton
class EventManager:
    def __init__(self):
        self.events = []
    def add_event(self, event):
        self.events.append(event)
    def print_events(self):
        print("Events : {}".format(self.events))

EventManager.add_event(0)
EventManager.add_event(1)
EventManager.add_event(2)
EventManager.print_events()
```

Output:

```
Events : [0, 1, 2]
```

Note that everything still works as expected when the singleton is imported and used in other modules.

---

**EDIT**

You asked :

> The thing is that I initialize the class with a variable like EventManager(var), what shall I do in this case?

The class will be instantiated right after its definition, i.e. the first time the module containing `EventManager` is imported. Since `EventManager` is a singleton, I don't think there is a point initializing the singleton with a variable. Even though it is possible:

```
def singleton_with_args(*args, **kwargs):
    def wrapper(cls):
        return cls(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

@singleton_with_args(0)
class EventManager:
    def __init__(self, first_event):
        self.events = [first_event]
    def add_event(self, event):
        self.events.append(event)
    def print_events(self):
        print("Events : {}".format(self.events))

EventManager.add_event(1)
EventManager.add_event(2)
EventManager.add_event(3)
EventManager.print_events()
```

Output:

```
Events : [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

It works but as I said, I don't think it's useful. You could as well use methods or module variables to initialize your singleton.

Comment: what is cls in the singleton function ? Do you mean EventManager ?

Comment: `singleton` is a decorator. When you write `@singleton` right before your class definition, it's exactly like writing `EventManager = singleton(EventManager)` right after your class definition.

Comment: Now, If I want to use EventManager in another module in another file. How can I do that ? How can i call it ? I tried to import the file then:

Comment: file.EventManager() ... but shows me an error saying  EventManager instance has no __call__ method

Comment: You have to use `file.EventManager` instead of `file.EventManager()` because `file.EventManager` is already an instance of your class `EventManager` (thanks to the singleton decorator)

Comment: The thing is that I initialize the class with a variable like EventManager(var), what shall I do in this case?

Answer (score 0):

This question is old but it was the first that came up for me, so I think it might be good to mention for others that there is a lot of talk about singletons being antipatterns, not pythonic etc.

After searching for a while, I think the best method is to use a [metaclass](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6798042/5242366):

> In general, it makes sense to use a metaclass to implement a
>   singleton. A singleton is special because is created only once, and a
>   metaclass is the way you customize the creation of a class. Using a
>   metaclass gives you more control in case you need to customize the
>   singleton class definitions in other ways.